# Move label(change position) while scrolling local ReportViewer

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll

I have *Windows Form Application*. There are 2 standart controls on a form as  `linklabel` and `reportviewer`. Data represented on `reportViewer` control sometimes so long and there possible some scrolling to keep all data for reading. It's normal situation. 
But I need simple feature, when user is scrolling up or down, `linkLabel` should move depend scrolling values to up or down, synchronously `reportViewer` content. LinkLabel location must be fixed comparatively `reportViewer`
[image]

*InitializeComponent method included:*

```
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(HRCard));
            this.reportViewer1 = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer();
            this.linkLabel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // reportViewer1
            // 
            this.reportViewer1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Kadr_Azerenerji.Report1.rdlc";
            this.reportViewer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.reportViewer1.Name = "reportViewer1";
            this.reportViewer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1020, 730);
            this.reportViewer1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.reportViewer1.RenderingComplete += new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.RenderingCompleteEventHandler(this.reportViewer1_RenderingComplete);
            this.reportViewer1.Scroll += new System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventHandler(this.reportViewer1_Scroll);
            // 
            // linkLabel1
            // 
            this.linkLabel1.AutoSize = true;
            this.linkLabel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(160, 314);
            this.linkLabel1.Name = "linkLabel1";
            this.linkLabel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(45, 15);
            this.linkLabel1.TabIndex = 2;
            this.linkLabel1.TabStop = true;
            this.linkLabel1.Text = "Diplom";
            this.linkLabel1.Visible = false;
            this.linkLabel1.LinkClicked += new System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(this.linkLabel1_LinkClicked);
            // 
            // HRCard
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 15F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1020, 730);
            this.Controls.Add(this.linkLabel1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.reportViewer1);
            this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(204)));
            this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
            this.Name = "HRCard";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.Manual;
            this.Text = "Azərenerji Kadr";
            this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.LavenderBlush;
            this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.HRCard_FormClosing);
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.HRCard_Load);
            this.Scroll += new System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventHandler(this.HRCard_Scroll);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: My guess when you were adding label in form designer you drop it on reportViewer and now label is located inside scrolling area and moves when you scroll. Instead you have to add label and reportViewer to same parent container (some panel or form itself) so that label position will be fixed compared to it. Label has to have higher z-order (or it will be under reportView).

Comment: @Sinatr yes, I have add reportViewer and label to same parent container, to form itself. I can't add label to reportViewer, it's not possible due to reportviewer capability.

Comment: Then why is label moving when you scroll reportview? Scrolling - changing viewport (displayed part) of content which doesn't fit. If scrolling moves your label, then it's belong to the scrolled content. Can you make bigger screenshot of your form and post form designer `InitializeComponents` content to see where label belongs to?

Comment: @Sinatr label not moving, moving reportviewer components. As I understandr scrollbar belong to reportViewer component. And as linklaber belong to form, moving reportviewer form not effect to linklabel and another form components (if exists). As shown on image, report viewer data moving, and linklabel fixed. But I want to move linklabel also, because of ui design beauty.

Comment: I misunderstood you completely (I blame picture, the label position should be the same to show what label stays!). You want directly opposite: move label together with scrolled content. You already subscribed to `Scroll` event, in this event you can check if scrolling occurs for `ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll` and do *something* with other [arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrolleventargs.aspx) to determine new label position.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82785/discussion-between-loviji-and-sinatr).

Comment: @Sinatr yes, I'm trying to handle reportviewer scrolling like private void reportViewer1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e) { linkLabel1.Location = new Point(50, 50); } , but it's not working. I want to handle (reflect) reportviewer scrolling. Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to use [`ScrollEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrolleventargs.aspx) to calculate a new point, not just some `Point(50,50)`, but more like `new Point(label.Left, label.Top + (e.NewValue - e.OldValue))`. Perhaps you will have to check `e.Type` and do some corrections. I don't have experience with `Scroll` event to give you a ready to use answer, sorry.